# Implementing a 6 seconds button in Android - how to pass variable in performClick()

Tags: java, android

I am building a button that when touched will beep 6 times (for 6 seconds) and only then click. So the expected behaviour is that hold your press for 6 seconds otherwise the click does not trigger.

With the help of the fine people who answered past questions on stackoverflow.com I've made it quite far. I tapped in the onTouch event and I used the performClick when 6 seconds have passed.

However because I return "true" on the onTouch event the click listener is always fired when I let the button go and if I set it to "false" than I never get the "ACTION_UP". I thought of a way around by passing variables in the perfromClick like "powerClick=true" or such but couldn't think of way. How can I prevent a click when the user only touches shortly?

The code of the ImageButton subclass
(I am new to Android and Java so I invite any insights on my approach which could be too "mispattern-friendly"):

```
package co.newcept.avoid6;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by dht on 01/12/15.
 */
 public class HoldItImageButton extends ImageButton {
    SoundPlayer soundPlayer;
    boolean isTouch;

    int beepCount = 0;

    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {


            if (isTouch) {
                beepCount++;
                Log.d("touch", Integer.toString(beepCount));

                if (beepCount >= 6) {

                    performClick();
                    beepCount = 0;
                    isTouch = false;
                    soundPlayer.playBomb();
                } else {
                    soundPlayer.playBeep();
                }

                timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }
    };

    public HoldItImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

        soundPlayer = SoundPlayer.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        super.onTouchEvent(event);

        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Log.d("touch", "onTouchEvent: DOWN");
            beepCount = 0;
            isTouch = true;
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);

        } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            Log.d("touch", "onTouchEvent: UP");

            beepCount = 0;
            isTouch = false;
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
            soundPlayer.playWoosh();
        }

        return true;
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, managed to solve it with setEnabled:

```
  if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        Log.d("touch", "onTouchEvent: DOWN");
        beepCount = 0;
        isTouch = true;
        timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        setEnabled(false);

    } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        Log.d("touch", "onTouchEvent: UP");

        beepCount = 0;
        isTouch = false;
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        soundPlayer.playWoosh();
        setEnabled(true);
    }
```